# Could you explain the code?

Tags: c++

The object created on heap is assigned to stack objects. Is it some
  kind of copy shallow copy?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
    private:
        char *name;
};

int main()
{
    Student *s = new Student();
    Student s1 = *s;
    Student s2;

    s2 = s1;
    delete s;

    // it will delete the object s and s1 and s2 are deleted when out of scope?
    //after the curly braces?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Normal assignment isn't affected in any way by where the objects involved are allocated.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how C++ works. That seems better dealt with by a text book, classroom or online tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

The statement `Student s1 = *s;` **makes a copy** of the content pointed to by `s`.  If `s` is deleted, it doesn't affect `s1`.  Same with `s2`.

**Edit 1:**
I didn't notice that you had a pointer in your post.  However, since you don't initialize it to point to anything, there is no memory leakage, and no copying problems.

However, if you do use a pointer, you will have to decide on how to copy the data.  Will you copy the pointer to the data?  Will you make a new copy of the data (The old data should be deleted)?

Using `std::string` instead of `char *` will help prevent this memory management issues.

Answer (score 5):

Correct, `s1` and `s2` contain copies of the content of `s`. i.e. `s1.name` and `s2.name` point to the same memory address as `s.name` (which is uninitialized as written). All stack variables (in this case `s`, `s1` and `s2`) get destroyed as you go out of scope.

Since `s` is just a pointer, nothing happens (and you would leak if you hadn't called `delete s` but `s1` and `s2` are classes so their destructors run when you go out of scope.